# how can I display large image smaller if i don't know its dimensions?

Tags: php, image, scale, image-resizing

I have the following problem. User can upload image, and I would like to display the image about 5 times smaller, without to cause distortion on the image. That is I would like to avoid. How can I find the width and height of the original image and divide it by 5?

I use php, forgot to mention that detail.

Regards,Zoran

Comment: hi. sorry, forgot to mention that, i use php

Comment: You will always distort the image by downscaling because you'll lose information in the process. The only thing you can do is avoid aliasing by low-pass filtering the image prior to or in the process of downscaling.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of your comments, you are looking for something simpler than the answers you are getting. Have you tried `getimagesize`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

You can do something like this:

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
echo $size[0]/5; //width
echo $size[1]/5; //height
```

This method also has the advantage of not having to rely on an image library like GD or anything.

Comment: That is correct. I am getting 0 0 right now, trying to find out what is going on. will add comment here later.

Comment: Thanks for solving this, my image was in array, that is why i get 0 0 in the first attempts. Now it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

call it with `FILTER_GAUSSIAN`

```
<?php
    $image = new Imagick( $filename );
    $imageprops = $image->getImageGeometry();
    if ($imageprops['width'] <= 200 && $imageprops['height'] <= 200) {
        // don't upscale
    } else {
        $image->resizeImage(200,200, imagick::FILTER_GAUSSIAN, 0.9, true);
    }
?>
```

The idea is to blur the image  by using gaussian filter and than subsampling it.

Comment: This is all nice, but is there is no simple option just to find existing image size and to divide it by 5?

Comment: no since it is will make a distortion, you must blur before subsampling

Comment: are you serious? Just use resample instead of resize if you want better quality.

Comment: use a resample filter like Lanczos, why would you blur the image and remove information first

Answer (score 0):

After image upload is done, use the following function:

```
<?php

function generate_image_thumbnail($source_image_path, $thumbnail_image_path){
    list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
    switch ($source_image_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
            break;
    }

    if ($source_gd_image === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width/5;
    $thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height/5;

    $thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
    imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
    return true;
}
?>
```

Pass right param to the function, it will do the job.

And make sure GD is enabled in your php settings. it uses gd library.

Comment: I am trying just to find existing image size and then to display it smaller, without to actually resize the image. Is there any function that can find the image size and divide it by 5 for example?

Comment: list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);

this line finds the height and width of the image and keep it in $source_image_height and $source_image_width

and in the line bellow

$thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width/5;
$thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height/5;

I have set the new thumbnail height and width, which is 5 times smaller than the original image